# Questions about $\sigma-$algebra

Tags: stochastic-processes

In my lecture notes there is the following:

The $\sigma-$algebra that is produced from a family of random variables $\{\xi_i, i \in I\}$ (where the set of indices $I$ can be finite or infinite) is defined as the smallest $\sigma-$algebra that contains the sets of the form $\xi_i^{-1}(B)$ where $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $i \in I$.

$$$$

- First question:

Isn't each $\sigma-$algebra procuded by a family of random variables???

- Second question:

Isn't there also an other $\sigma-$algebra that contains elements of the form $\xi_i^{-1}(B)$ other than the smallest one???

Comment: When you say infinite, do you mean any cardinality?

Comment: I suppose so. @snarski